# Execute my update query in sqllite with case statement

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working in an android application and I am using sqllite in my application. I want to update my sql with a query that contains case statement. Please suggest me a correct solution to execute this query and return me an int value to confirm if the table is updated successfully.

My query ::

```
UPDATE TblAgencies SET Selected= CASE WHEN ID=6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: Arun, what error or problems do you get? May try something like "UPDATE TblAgencies SET Selected= (Select CASE WHEN ID=6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END a)"

Comment: The query works correctly, But I want to execute it in update method on SQLiteDatabase class

Comment: Here's the idiom of doing updates with SQLiteDatabase - I don't think you can use CASE within your update - http://android.codota.com/scenarios/527f776ada0ab642c1a725f3/android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase?tag=antelope

Answer (score 2):

`update TblAgencies set Selected = (ID == 6);` will do this.
As to "did the update work correctly" -- that's standard API work, nothing to do with the query itself.

Comment: The query works correctly, but how can I implement this in the update method in SQLiteDatabase

Comment: Use the `execSQL(String sql)` method directly. The `update(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)` method doesn't appear to have what you need here. The only alternative would be to examine the `SQLiteDatabase` object source and see if there's a way to roll your own `update()` into it, but the `execSQL()` method is definitely easiest.

Answer (score 1):

I wont do the programming for you but here how you do it.

```
int res = db.update(table, values, whereClause, whereArgs);
if(res>0) etc...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 try
            {
                database=openOrCreateDatabase("solutiondb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                database.execSQL("update patientdetails set name='"+naMe+"',dob='"+DOB+"',gender='"+genDer+"',height="+heiGht+",weight="+weiGht+",bmi="+BMI+",bloodgroup='"+bloodGroup+"',profession='"+proFession+"',address='"+addRess+"',contact="+contactNumber+",smoking='"+smoKing+"',drinking='"+drinKing+"',maritalstatus='"+maritalStatus+"',physician='"+phySican+"' where id="+patientId+"");
                Toast.makeText(PersonalInformationActivity.this, "Your Personal Details Are Saved Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                dialog.dismiss();
                intent=new Intent(PersonalInformationActivity.this, PersoxcsdActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                database.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException exception)
            {

            }
```

Comment: How is this related to the question?